# Where is fx:jar in NetBeans? - JavaFX

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, jar, javafx-2

I am developing a standalone JavaFX application using NetBeans 7.2.1 and having problems with [Autoproxy Configuration](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#4).

In JavaFX documents I found this: [13.3.5 Disabling the Autoproxy Configuration in the Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/troubleshooting.htm). It says "If you need to disable the automatic proxy configuration in the application, specify a JavaFX-Feature-Proxy manifest entry in the fx:jar with the None as a value". But I can't find fx:jar anywhere in ant scripts of NetBeans.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm#CIAEEAGG might help

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans stores JavaFX related ant tasks in `nbproject/jfx-impl.xml`

Although this file is autogenerated and if you want to have modified jar generation you need to write new target from scratch in `build.xml`

Update: quoting `jfx-impl.xml` created by NetBeans 7.2

```
// fx:jar
var jar = project.createTask("fx_jar");
jar.setProject(project);
var destfile = project.getProperty("pp_jar_destfile");
jar.setDestfile(destfile);
```

It's an ant task accessed through script.

Comment: But there is no fx:jar in there. fx:jar is nowhere... Is fx:jar created by NetBeans or not?

Comment: I think I will have to try to make my own "ant-fx-script" without using NetBeans, because I simply can't find a way to disable that autoproxy configuration. Or maybe I give up JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for now was creating a .bat file. At least on Windows it does the job.

The .bat file contains this command:

```
  start javaw -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true -jar myapp.jar
```

This command runs the application without leaving the prompt window open.